# How to see $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a smooth manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

I may be missing something obvious here, but I want to understand how $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a smooth manifold. I know it has to be since it's diffeomorphic to the torus $T^n$.

What I have for a setup is this:
$f:\mathbb{Z}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a group action defined by $(g,m)\mapsto gm:=g+m$, where $g=(g^1, \ldots, g^n)$ and $m=(m^1, \ldots, m^n)$ and $g+m$ is component addition.

$f$ induces a map $F: \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n\to T^n$ which is given by $([x^1], \ldots, [x^n])\mapsto (e^{ix^1}, \ldots, e^{ix^n})$.

My confusion is that set theoretically (unless my abstract algebra is completely off), $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n= \{m\mathbb{Z}^n\mid m\in \mathbb{R}^n \}$ this seems pretty discrete to me.....so how can I see this space as a smooth space?

Comment: Take $n=1$ and see that the space is not pretty discrete. The coset space $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = \{x + \mathbb{Z} \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: Do you know what the quotient topology is?

Comment: Ah yes, vaguely-I guess I should think of the quotient space with respect to the quotient topology. I know being open in the quotient top is induced by the covering space. Is that the same for smoothness?

Comment: $\Bbb R^n / \Bbb Z^n$ can be thought of as the hypercube $[0,1]^n$ whose pairs of opposite faces have been identified ("glued together"). This way of seeing it shows that it is obviously not discrete.

Comment: You have to know the definition more than vaguely, otherwise no answer to the question will be clear.

Comment: FWIW, this [interactive drawing program](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/teach/software/Torus/index.html) may help illustrate the covering action and the quotient topology when $n = 2$....

Comment: All of this is helpful and I re-examined the definition of quotient topology and @Didlier's explanation/visualization was really helpful. Thank you all!